# Add a KeyListener in my Login JPanel

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jcomponent

I've a `JPanel` that works as Login page. This `JPanel` contains a `JTextField` for inserting username, a `JPasswordField` for password and, obviously, a Confirm `JButton`.

I would like that authentication procedure will be executed even if user types `ENTER` from its clipboard.

So I let my class implements KeyListener, register the class with

```
addKeyListener(this);
```

and override the following method:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        centrale.autentica(nome_utente.getText(), password.getPassword());
}
```

but nothing happens. I noticed that things work if I register even the JTextField as consumer for key event, so I should do

```
addKeyListener(this);
myjtextfield.addKeyListener(this);
myjpasswordfield.addKeyListener(this);
```

but it seems a bit ugly to me. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener.

In general Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. However in this case you don't even need Key Bindings.

For the `JTextField` you can just add an `ActionListener` to the text field and if the user presses Enter the ActionListener will be invoked.

Also you probably have a "Login" button on the form so you can make the Login button the default button so it is activated when the Enter Key is pressed even if the button doesn't have focus.

```
getRootPane().setDefaultButton( loginButton );
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a key listener. Just add an ActionListener to the JPasswordField; it should respond to pressing "Enter".